# Google Calendar Api v3 does not return Profile IDs of event attendees

Tags: c#, .net, google-plus, google-calendar-api

I changed the [.NET Quickstart code sample](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample) for Google Calendar Api v3 minimally, regarding event listing, to get the profile IDs of all attendees:

```
foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
{
    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
    {
        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
    Console.WriteLine(" Attendees: {0}", string.Join(", ",
        eventItem.Attendees?.Select(attendee => attendee.Id) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
}
```

Unfortunately I can receive the attendee's names and mail addresses but not their IDs - they are always `null`. The documentation says:

> The attendee's Profile ID, if available. It corresponds to theid [sic] field in the People collection of the Google+ API

I ensured that some of the attendees are active Google Plus users.

I also added a request parameter, it did not help:

```
request.MaxAttendees = 100;
```

What am I doing wrong, or why is this impossible? Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

To check if the ID really exists use the [People.get Try-it](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#try-it). A successful call returns a [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#try-it) which contains the ID (if it exists). Don't forget to provide `*` as your parameter in "`fields`".

Comment: Which ID shall I test? I have no one (except my own).